# Can I undeclare a variable in C++?

Tags: c++

Say that, for some reason, I don't need a variable anymore: can I "undeclare" it?

For example: the delete operator deallocates the memory dedicated to a pointer, can I "delete" the pointer itself too?

Comment: If you mean that the variable points to nothing: `myVar = null;`. If you however mean that you want to use the same variable name again but, let's say, as a different type then no. You can scope a variable so that it only exists within that scope with `{` and `}`.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen: `= null` just isn't valid C++. Unlike Java and SQL, most C++ types aren't nullable (pointers being the exception, and then it's `nullptr`)

Comment: @MSalters: The OP had pointers as an example hence the `null` in my comment which should have been `nullptr` or `NULL`.

Answer (score 12):

You can't undeclare a variable, just like you can't become unborn. But you can limit its existence with a scope:

```
{
  int a = 42;
}

// a doesn't exist here
```

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't "undeclare" a variable. It is 'undeclared' when it goes out of scope.

Note that variable declaration is only relevant during compilation. Once the program has been compiled, variables are no longer 'declared' or 'undeclared'. Object instances get created at run time, but variables are declared at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide its value locally:

```
int a = 10;

void some_function()
{
    int a = 100;
    // a is 100 here
}
```

Comment: This is not overriding. This is _hiding_.

Comment: You're not hiding the value, you're hiding the name. There are two completely independent things called "a", and the outer `a` still exists and has the value 10. It's just not visible inside the function.